# Htaccess misconfiguration error 500

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, http-status-code-500

I have implemented a new .htaccess file at http://www.ssdpsjal.tk
My code is -

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ n/index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^$ /index [L]
Redirect /administrator /sadmin1
```

I use CodeIgniter. You can visit the website to see the error.

Moreover I have tried this .htacccess on my local server and it isn't showing any such errors there (I think)

My Document Structure is as follows

```
--- ssdpsjal.tk                //given by host. Non-writable
  --n                          //the folder where website is stored
  --web_based_editor           //something my website uses
  --.htaccess file             //Htaccess file that I told about
  --Some other stuff not relevent to the question
```

**EDIT**

I have changed the code many times and after some changes I found the error to be occurring at `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ n/index.php/$1 [L]`

**NOTE**

The `index` at `RewriteRule ^$ /index [L]` is not Index.php It is actually a function(method) of my codeigniter controller

Actual URL without .htaccess is http://www.ssdpsjal.tk/n/index.php/s/index

Note the `index` on the last of sentence, it is that one!

Comment: What does your `error.log` say?

Comment: I can't see the error log as the Host Service Provider doesn't let me to do. (I am a free User :( )

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ n/index.php/$1 [L]` why is this n/ ? are you just trying to bypass showing `index.php`?

Comment: Actually `n` is my Folder Name where the website is stored at! I am trying to hide `/n/index.php` from my website's URL

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteRule ^administrator /sadmin1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

or just change this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ n/index.php/$1 [L]
```

into:

```
RewriteRule ^$ n/index.php [L]
```

Comment: Now I am getting 404 Not Found Error

Comment: in the same  folder as .htaccess or in folder called 'n' ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your configuration but are you sure mod_rewrite exists?

Perhaps:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)  http://www.ssdpsjal.tk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ n/index.php [L]
Redirect /administrator /sadmin1
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please See the Note I have just inserted! Any Help Appreciated!

Comment: Yes, I am sure that mod_rewrite exists.

Comment: It is now going to the URL `http://www.ssdpsjal.tk/www.ssdpsjal.tk/n/index.php` and showing `Too many Redirects` error

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer to my own question.

The .htaccess file is perfectly correct. The problem was with the webhost. They were updating their services without any warning (Notice came After 5-6 hours) due to which many services were shut down.

Well, i changed my Webhost to a new one which is way better. ( [000WebHost](http://www.000webhost.comm) )